# How to get all the Services from Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

How do I obtain all the services after StartupClass has run?

We have a Startup Configure Services class which 
runs multiple dependency injection.

```
 serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDepartmentRepository, DepartmentRepository>();
 serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDepartmentAppService, DepartmentAppService>();
```

Team is using Xunit Test Project and wants to grab all the Service collection list for Xunit.

Need services from this below:

```
new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot("C:\\Test\\Test.WebAPI")
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath("C:\\Test\\Test.WebAPI")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build()).UseStartup<Startup>());
```

Comment: hi @John currently running integration tests, just need test repository, services which all work together, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services in `ServiceCollection` are represented by the [`ServiceDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class. You can get a list of all service descriptors by chaining a [`ConfigureTestServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.webhostbuilderextensions.configuretestservices?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method to your `WebHostBuilder` (you have to install [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost/) package)

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;

....

IWebHost CreateWebHost(out ServiceDescriptor[] allServices)
{
    ServiceDescriptor[] grabbedServices = null;

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        // ... other stuff ...
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        // add the following call:
        .ConfigureTestServices(services => {
            // copy all service descriptors
            grabbedServices = services.ToArray(); 
        })
        // build the host now to trigger the above chain
        .Build();

    allServices = grabbedServices;
    return host;
}
```

It is then convenient to use like this:

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestSomething()
{
    // arrange

    var host = CreateWebHost(out var services);
    // ... do something with the services

    // act
    // assert    
}
```

The reason we have to use `ConfigureTestServices` (and not `ConfigureServices`) is that `ConfigureServices` is always invoked before the methods in the `Startup` class, whereas `ConfigureTestServices` is invoked afterward.

#### UPDATE

Of course, it's also possible to just store the reference to `ServiceCollection` in a variable/field, and enumerate the services whenever necessary.

Comment: thanks, could I also just store in a Service Collection variable? sorry, did not write question clearly, we can keep this answer, and write alternative, thanks ! @felix-b

Comment: I've just fixed a bug in the answer, it should be 'ConfigureTestServices' and not 'ConfigureServices`.

Answer (score 0):

So I understood your question that you want to test you services and have problems with loading them in test project.
I'd say you don't need to. In unit tests every time you test a *single* service. This service you instantiate directly:

```
var target= new ServiceToTest();
```

So you reference your testED project from your test project. In case your implementation is internal, add to your testED project an AssemblyInfo.cs file and put the following inside:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestProject")]
```

Whenever you test your MyServiceToTest1, in case it has a dependecy to MyServiceTest2, you don't have to load or instantiate MyServiceTest2. Instead you mock it, e.g. with *moq*.